# MySQL if 2 hours between two dates and times

Tags: mysql

This is a tough one i'm trying to figure out.

This is my table:

```
task_reminders
    - id
    - date
    - time
```

I want to `SELECT ALL` rows which has a date and time 3 hours after the current (`NOW`) date and time (UTC). It is tough because the date and time columns are separate.

**Examples:**

For example, if the current date and time is `2019-01-20 08:30:00`, I want to select all rows that have a date and time that is 3 hours after that time (only counting hours).

```
2019-01-20 11:50:00 this would work
2019-01-20 11:10:00 this would work too

2019-01-20 10:00:00 would NOT work
2019-01-20 12:00:00 would NOT work
```

Another example: If the current date and time is `2019-01-19 11:20:00`, these would and would not work:

```
2019-01-20 02:50:00 this would work
2019-01-20 02:30:00 this would work too

2019-01-20 01:10:00 would NOT work
2019-01-20 03:45:00 would NOT work
```

It is kind of hard because the `DATE` and `TIME` are separate in my database. How would i do this? Thank you!

Comment: I would unseparate the date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just want the hours to be different from each other by 3, you can check for 2 conditions:

1. `HOUR(NOW())` is < 21, in which case the dates should be the same and `HOUR(time) = HOUR(NOW()) + 3`; or
2. `HOUR(NOW())` >= 21, in which case the date should be 1 more than `CURDATE()` and `HOUR(time) =`HOUR(NOW()) - 21`

So your query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM task_reminders
WHERE HOUR(`time`) = HOUR(NOW()) +  3 AND `date` = CURDATE() OR
      HOUR(`time`) = HOUR(NOW()) - 21 AND `date` = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

**Note**

1. Since hours wrap, there is no need to include the conditions about `HOUR(NOW())` relative to 21 in the query
2. I'm assuming your `date` and `time` columns are of datatype `DATE` and `TIME` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this it will compare date and hour but skip time and seconds as you want

```
SELECT *
FROM task_reminders
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CAST(CONCAT(`edate`, ' ', `etime`) AS DATETIME), '%Y-%m-%d %H') >=
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR) , '%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Please check sqlfiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bec7a/1

Comment: Does this just account for the hours though?

Comment: Please check out the updated code it will consider till hours only.

Answer (score -1):

Use this query and replace the table and variable names

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sent_date FROM invitations WHERE email='$email' AND uid='$session_uid' AND `sent_date` < SUBDATE( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 HOUR)");
```